# Acceder a datos en una tupla

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate("2.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{
    'databaseURL':'https://new1-3b819.firebaseio.com/'
})

ref = db.reference('/Producto')
r1 = ref.get()
for key in r1.values(): #items() or values()
    for key in key.items():
        print(key)
```

El cual me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
('Cantidad', 10)
('Precio', 55)
('id', 9878)
('nombre', 'usb')
('ubicación', 'exe2')
('Cantidad', 2)
('Nombre', 'usb-blue')
('id', 98989)
('precio', 34)
('ubicación', 'exe2')
[Finished in 4.3s]
```

Pero lo que necesito es que solo me muestre, por ejemplo, los campos que tienen unicamente como llave `'id'`

Esto es lo que espero obtener:

> id - 9878
>
> id - 98989

En vez de toda la lista que obtengo.

Comment: Relacionando el código que pones con la salida que produce, se deduce que la `key` que imprimes es una tupla. Los elementos de la tupla se acceden como si fueran elementos de una lista, por tanto bastaría cambiar el último `print(key)` por `if key[0]=='id': print(key)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En vez de usar `items()` puedes usar simplemente un `get()` para obtener el valor para la llave que necesitas, que en este caso es `id`:

```
for key in r1.values():
    id = key.get('id')
    print('id - %s' % id)
```

Debería dar como resultado:

```
id - 9878 
id - 98989
```

De hecho, si `r1.values()` retorna una lista de diccionarios, puedes usar una lista por comprensión para obtener todos los IDs:

```
ids = [d.get('id') for d in r1.values()]
for id in ids:
    print('id - %s' % id)
```

Donde el resultado de `ids` es una lista:

```
[9878, 98989]
```